# TextureView Always show only the first frame

Tags: android, textureview

I want to change the visibility of the textureView when I call

```
textureView.setFocusable(false);
textureView.setVisibility(GONE);
```

After that, the textureView is not visible, this is normal, but when I call

```
textureView.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
textureView.setFocusable(true);
......
mediaPlayer.start();
```

After that, the video is definitely already playing (because I heard the sound), but the picture on the textureView has been stuck on the first frame. Why?
Ask for guidance, thank you.

Comment: try textureView.requestLayout(); it may help you.

Comment: @kAvEh  it is nothing help.    Is there any other way?

Comment: sorry I dont know any other way for this.

Comment: @kAvEh  OK ,Thank u anyway.